# Add Calendar event to Lotus Notes Calendar Android Java

Tags: java, android, calendar, lotus-notes, android-calendar

I use the following code to add and event into the users default calendar from my android application:

```
private void insertCalendarEvent() {

try {

    Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getStartDATE().getTimeInMillis()) 
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getEndDATE().getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getNotebook())
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getExtra1())
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone())
    .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);

    if(model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getName() == null) {
        calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getActivityTypeCODE().GetDescription());
    }else {
        calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getActivityTypeCODE().GetDescription() + "-" + model.getCurrentActivityEvent().getName());
    }           
    calIntent = getCompanyEmail(calIntent);

    startActivity(calIntent);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // log exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

This works fine when the email account is exchange, google mail or pop3 account and the user has configured that account as the default calendar on the device. Essentially the user is presented with the event activity and can make changes if required at this point, then save or cancel the event.

However my clients are using Lotus Notes traveler to handle their email and calendars on their android devices. This code does not put the event into the Lotus Notes Calendar but into the phones default calendar even if its not set up with an account.

How can I configure the phone settings or application code to insert an event into the users Lotus Notes Calendar?